# HTTPTargetConnection - why proxy.pathsuffix gets appended to URL

Tags: apigee

I have created multiple target-end points based on my back-end servers. Each target end point has a fixed URL.

URL is configured as -

```
<HTTPTargetConnection>
    <URL>https://example.com/test/</URL>
</HTTPTargetConnection>
```

I noticed that "proxy.pathsuffix" is automatically getting added to url (https://example.com/test/). How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

A bit outdated in reply - but, Assign Message works for this (to avoid JavaScript):

```
<AssignVariable>
        <Name>target.copy.pathsuffix</Name>
        <Value>false</Value>
</AssignVariable>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a new JavaScript callout policy in your proxy request flow. In this JavaScript callout, simply add a single line:

```
context.setVariable("target.copy.pathsuffix", false);
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid JavaScript callout to just set property, is there any other way

Comment: Unfortunately not. It doesn't work with an AssignMessage - not really sure why.

Comment: AssignMessage has a known bug that doesn't overwrite path.suffix, so the only workaround currently is to use javascript.

Comment: @kamesh just got wind that this might actually be possible with AssignMessage now - have you tried?

Comment: make sure you try the assign message policy while on the target side.